# Is it possible to use ON_DEMAND pricing for Cloud SQL any longer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I keep finding old posts about an on demand pricing option for Cloud SQL, but I see no more references in Google's documentation on how to enable it? Did this feature go away?

If so, can someone provide me a recommendation on an alternative for hosting a MySQL DB? Cloud SQL is just too much if I have to always be running the instance.

Comment: You can stop your instance when you don't use it if you want. What are your DB requirement if you look for an alternative?

Comment: I currently have < 1GB of data, only a handful of users, and it needs infrequent access, so I really don't want to have to run the server constantly

Comment: Do you use raw SQL or do you use a framework to access to the database? Do you have latency requirements?

Answer (score 0):

As per the GCP [doc](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/pricing#2nd-gen-pricing) Cloud SQL for MySQL pricing is charged for every second. This means that each second of usage counts towards a full billable minute. For example, If you use an instance for 1.5 seconds or 2.49 seconds, in both cases you are billed for 2 seconds.

Comment: Adding to what this comment has, you can also use the [GCP calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) to compare it against other providers.